# Leave text inside brackets only

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Could someone help me to solve following issue:
I found elements on page which I was looking for with

```
WebElement h2 = ol.findElement(By.xpath("../h2" + h2current));
        String h2currentShorted = h2.getText();
        String h2currentShorted2 = h2currentShorted.substring(24);
```

Now, original text is on several languages and therefore is different size (number of characters). Examples:

```
Tidligere stillinger ( 1. Jul 2016 - 1. Jul 2017)
Vergangene Gesamtwertung ( 1. Jul 2016 - 1. Jul 2017)
Previous standings ( 1. Jul 2016 - 1. Jul 2017)
```

Above is text in three different languages. How can I pickup only text inside brackets and nothing else.
With above code I remove characters which are not necessary, but if there is one solution for all languages - just to pickup text inside brackets?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others stated, use a regular expression but consider a more elegant way using groups.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\((.*)\\).*");
Matter m = p.matcher(h2.getText());
String s = m.group(1);
```

The variable `s` will contain only the text inside the brackets.

Comment: This a perfect solution. Thank you @Bastian Schoettle

Comment: Most probably I did something wrong when input that into test (first line shows error), I am getting this error: **illegal escape character**

Please assist and thank you

Comment: Sorry, in java one has to escape the backslashes. I've forgot that when typing the code but I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you one more time. Perfect

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex like

```
\(.*\)
```

or use `String.indexOf` to determine the positions of the ( and ).

Comment: Regex is solution. Thank you Index of will not work since that there are not same length on different language